# Corporate / Private integration with public sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I work for a very large, very public software company (Adobe Systems), and we've recently been discussing a StackExchange-like Q&A system for in-house use --- this would be questions we ask about roadmaps or features, where the message to the outside world isn't quite polished enough yet, or the answer can't be given until [insert date here].

We still need to discuss it and have an elegant way of referencing those discussions, but would very much like to have a "public/private" flag, where we could answer questions, and, if shareable, be able to share the Q&A with the outside world.

It's my understanding that to do that with the existing SE system, we'd have to have a private/corporate instance, and then MANUALLY transfer the Question and Answer to the regular, public SE network.

My question is: Is that accurate? Is there a way that we as an organization could ask and answer questions 'in private' and then with a 'flip of a switch' make the Q&A topic 'public'?

I tried to research this and found some [examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160031/impact-of-corporate-accounts-on-the-community-and-compatibility-with-the-site-in) that are close, but not exact, as they deal with either private instances or private user accounts, or corporate accounts.

I'm hoping someone out there might know if this is possible? I'm sure we're not alone in this being a compelling use case.

Answer (score 12):

There's no support for this sort of thing in the system at all, I'm afraid - the system was simply not designed with strict access control in mind.

And I'm not entirely convinced it would be a good idea in any case. The usefulness of a good answer tends to depend heavily on the author's ability to write for his audience, and provide references for background information as-needed; with two different audiences (public and private) and potentially two separate (and constantly-changing) sets of reference material, this would become prohibitively difficult: imagine an answer written for an internal audience, with references to internal, pre-release documentation suddenly made public - it would very likely be confusing at best and potentially misleading or useless. Avoiding this would require some talented editors acting as intermediaries, thus removing the advantage of a single repository for both public and private posts.

I recommend instead creating an internal repository, either a good discussion forum or a wiki, and then empowering and encouraging employees to both share information privately and draw on this when answering publicly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer / suggestions!  I'm not sure the issues you brought up with such a system are all that difficult to overcome with a bit of code (checking links/permissions on submit, for example), but you're right it's probably not a fundamental SE use case.

Comment: @strack: As I see it, it is not primarily a technical limitation, but rather that content written for Adobe employees is unlikely to be useful for the general public without a significant rewrite.

Comment: Thanks @BartvanIngenSchenau, but you'd be surprised how much content is fit for both public and internal, but has certain release dates on it. Especially in the Solutions Consulting org. But, yeah, it sounds like we will just have to manually transfer. Thx.

Comment: Oh, it's definitely a technical limitation as well, @Bart - I've looked into this a bit, and the changes needed to allow something like this would be *extensive*.