# How can I dissolve the "SO teams" site started privately to public SE sites after some time?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, private-beta, stack-overflow-for-teams, so-enterprise

I have been a member in SO communities since 2011, and I find the information here well organized and easily searchable from the Internet.

Let's say I am developing a software product called *"Saarathy"* for a global customer base. I already see that people will have lots of questions for it on its usage and maintenance once released. So instead of having only a "Help" menu in that application, I want to start arranging those support topics in SO style Q&A.

Like 150+ free SE sites, I can't suggest for this site as it's not on the market yet. Hence, **"SO Teams"** is the way to go for now.

Once this product is available, I want all the general populace including current SE users to start see and contribute into it.

What is the way to make my currently private "SO Teams" available to the public, like the other 150+ SE sites?

---

**Related**:

- [Corporate / Private integration with public sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239159/163449)
- [Is it possible to create Public Teams?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410645/514235)

Comment: I suspect the (multimillion) dollar question might be how SE could run (and be convinced to run) outsourced public Q&A as a service.  Right now SE's charging per seat(?) so hosted Q&A not something that's designed to handle casual usage

Comment: You could consider looking into [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives), but you'd have to manually curate/migrate your team's content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean you want to essentially convert a team into a full site that is part of the Stack Exchange network, no that is not possible and never will be. There will also never be any way for migrating content from a team to an existing public site.

Past that, we generally don't create sites for specific products anymore. We create sites for subject areas, so a public site on our network for only that one product would not be considered viable.

I won't reiterate any of the points made, but your [second related article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410645/is-it-possible-to-create-public-teams) contains a lot of useful information on how you might leverage Teams as a support solution independently, without integrating it into our network.